# Failure to install old versions of transformers in colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, transformer-model

I recently had a problem installing Transformer version 2.9.0 in colab.

[image: Its image]

[image]

Comment: What is the full error? Image seems to be broken.

Comment: I showed its continuation with another photo

Comment: try `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: I updated it but got another error:"ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colab has recently upgraded to Python 3.9. There is a temporary mechanism for users to run Python 3.8 runtime (Linux-5.10.147+-x86_64-with-glibc2.29 platform). This is available from the Command Palette via the "Use fallback runtime version" command when connected to a runtime. The issue can be tracked [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3450).

Comment: Thank you . As you said, this is a temporary solution. Is there a permanent way to reuse Python 3.8 in colab?

Answer (score 1):

As Scka said, the problem occurred due to the update of Python by colab.

Python 3.7 can be installed every time on the notebook: with the following commands:

!sudo apt-get install python3.7

!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3
/usr/bin/python3.7 1

!sudo update-alternatives --config python3

!sudo apt install python3-pip

after it

!python --version

then

!sudo apt-get install python3.7-distutils

Comment: This helped A LOT!